# Restore integrity of compromised live boot iso

Tags: linux

Assuming  that BIOS integrity can be restored by resetting with the manufacturers bypass code, can a USB device running a corrupted/compromised Linux distro be restored to a state of integrity? The distros are FWUL 3.1 and Qubes  respectively on a Acer E5-521 which has had it's hard drive and WIFI card pulled. Despite these precautions the attacker still has access via the wired Ethernet connection somehow. Can I isolate the USB iso and re-secure/ harden it?

Comment: Perhaps English is not your native tongue, but this reads like it was created by copy-pasting various bits of vaguely security and computer related phrases together randomly. The question contains enough grammatical and conceptual errors that it's difficult to discern its intended meaning.

Comment: Indeed sir it is not, evident by the garbled syntax you remarked upon Compounding matters I am woefully ignorant about computing, so I beg your patience friend. Yes my terminology may be inaccurate and expose my lack of knowledge but the the first sentence seems fairly comprehensible: if the boot sequence isn't corrupted from BIOS, can a corrupted  live boot USB iso of Linux be restored to a safe,secure state and how. Do not disdain me for my ignorance sir, is not the purpose of this site to elucidation? In my country we are under the absolute worst form of state managed servitude. Namste

Comment: I intended no offense, I merely wanted to inform you that it was going to be difficult to answer your question because it was hard to parse. We get spam/troll questions here (just like everywhere else on the internet) where if you squint enough you might be tempted to waste time answering whatever meaning you can dredge out of the noise. I wrote the comment so if your question was indeed asked in good faith you could edit it and hopefully get a solution for your problem. I see you did, and it reads much more clearly now!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that, and yes, unfortunately I'm quite sincere both myself and my family are affected. I can understand your perspective, I hadn't considered your experience reading posts. In my home country the State has unfettered access to the metadata and telephonic networks, wired or otherwise, and brazenly stripped it's citizens of their rights to freedom and privacy. The situation is absolutely the most pernicious form of authoritarian government. The exercise of harmless personal life styles and freedoms of the citizens can and do result in decades of incarceration, fines...

Answer (score 1):

If the iso file you have is not compromised, you can just reboot and load it.

The main issue is not the integrity of your system, but your Operation Security (OpSec). This is the issue that most people forget, and what brings them down. Hardware compromise is **very** difficult to pull of, software compromise less so, but operation security compromise happens all the time.

Comment: They are not, it's like trying to get a cup of clean water while standing in a sewer. Yes, you are so right: I was complacent, uninformed, disbelieving... You can believe I'll be reading the hash of every file, studiously apply every patch, and embrace cryptography as a new religion if I'm able to ...